# Running distVincentyEllipsoid() over each row of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to run the distVincentyEllipsoid() function over every row of a data.table. Sadly, it does not appear to be vectorized:

```
library(geosphere)
mydat[, dest_home_orig := round(distVincentyEllipsoid(c(zip_long, zip_lat), c(orig_long, orig_lat))/1609.34,1)]`
```

Tried:

`mydat2[,.(round(distVincentyEllipsoid(c(zip_long, zip_lat), c(orig_long, orig_lat))/1609.34,1)), by=.I]`

*Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2*

Workaround, using a for loop (!). I would like a data.table solution if one exists. I've seen other answers but they involve joins. This should be a straight up within-table operation.

Dput below:

```
mydat <- structure(list(zip_long = c(-65.9, -65.9, -72.52, -72.68, -72.59
), zip_lat = c(18.37, 18.37, 42.37, 42.26, 42.1), orig_long = c(-117.18972222, 
-121.92916667, -122.31166667, -87.90805556, -118.40722222), orig_lat = c(32.73361111, 
37.36277778, 47.45, 41.97722222, 33.9425)), .Names = c("zip_long", 
"zip_lat", "orig_long", "orig_lat"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Try  `by = 1:nrow(mydat2)` or similar. You can't call `.I` within the `by` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that eventually. I was just hoping for something more elegant-looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super old thread, but I found it while trying to do the same thing.

```
library(geosphere)
mydat$distance <- apply(mydat, 1, function(row) {
  point1 <- c(as.numeric(row["zip_long"]), as.numeric(row["zip_lat"]))
  point2 <- c(as.numeric(row["orig_long"]), as.numeric(row["orig_lat"]))
  distm(point1, point2, fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
})
```